# Password Strength Meter Problem

Tags: javascript, passwords, password-checker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password Strength Meter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921330/password-strength-meter)

Hi I have created a password meter script which you can see:
[here](http://jsfiddle.net/RSq4L/13/)

This code might seem a little repetitive but I like it. 
But for some reason after the fair strength when I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, <kbd>TAB</kbd>, <kbd>CAPS LOCK</kbd>, etc. it goes to the next strenght for some reason but I just cant figure out why.

Best Regards,
Shawn

**Hope you can help :)**

Comment: Include _relevant_ code in your question, don't _only_ link to it. (-1)

Comment: `ratingsMsg` is probably better implemented as a function that tests rating ranges, rather than a repetitive Array that requires specific declarations for every possible score permutation.

Comment: Lots of feedback on this function already provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921330/password-strength-meter/6921344.  Please implement those suggestions before you go asking for more on the same function.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it doesn't anything already discussed in the previous question.

Comment: This is not fair at all. I just had a problem didnt have to down vote me at all !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest changing your event listener from an `onkeydown` to `onkeyup`. It seems to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RSq4L/14/).